# Tire damage shows a little fuzzy white underneath tear flap. Should replace?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

[image]

I scraped a curb going slow while parking. There's some white under the flap (polyester I guess). Is it repairable, closing up the flap with glue? If so, what sort of glue? Or should I get a new tire?

The tires are Michelin Pilot Super Sport 295/35ZR19 (100Y) for front wheels.

Tread plies: 1 polyester, 1 polyamide, 2 steel

Sidewall plies: 1 polyester

(Shelby GT350)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 4):

That is a tire that you have to replace.

As the plies are exposed then the tire can fail at that point, or it can fail at another point.

For safety, yours and others, replace it.

Do not try to repair it.